# Microsoft Add-in Store Submission - Sign in with office 365 credential

Tags: office-addins, word-addins, office-store

I published my Word Add-in to store and got rejected by the validation team.

My Add-in have sign-in function that only a user in our tenant - [Thread](https://thread.legal/) can login and use the add-in.

When the add-in work on Word Online, when sign-in to office 365 it will automatically get credential that stored in cookie to perform an authentication.

But the validation team reject my add-in by this reason

> 1. Insert your add-in.
> 2. Click on “Sign in with office 365” and click “Allow” to permit the authentication window to open.
> 3. Notice we are not given a chance to enter any credentials and does not progress beyond the loading process, as shown above.

I have specified it in the description when i submited the manifest file.

> To use this add-in, you must be a Thread subscription customer as it requires your Thread web application credentials to sign in. For example, if you are using the add-in with Word Online documents, it will automatically use your Thread web application credentials to sign in.

As i understand, when we login by Azure AD if we already have credential it will not show the pop-up to enter username and password.

Anyone know how to by pass this. Please help

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Since this add-in is only applicable for user's in your own tenant, I wouldn't recommend leveraging the Office Store. The Store isn't designed to handle internal deployments of add-ins. Instead, take a look at [Use centralized deployment to publish Office Add-ins](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/publish/centralized-deployment). This allows you to publish your add-in to all users on your tenant.

Comment: but based on this https://dev.office.com/blogs/office-store-validation-policy-changes-to-support-apps-and-add-ins-that-target-larger-organizations-and-enterprises . It specified that we can upload add-in that target for large organisation

Comment: If you can comply with the strict criteria, than you can certainly use the store. That said, this method (and blog post) pre-date the release of [Centralized Deployment](https://blogs.office.com/en-us/2017/05/31/announcing-general-availability-of-the-office-365-centralized-deployment-service/). Unless you have a very specific scenario that requires leveraging the Store, using Centralized Deployment is really the way to go.